# Setting up iplanet web server

Tags: glassfish, webserver

I am trying to install iplanet web server 7.0.15 64bit. keep getting the error

"attach to native process failed"

I am using Linux mint 15 64bit

Searched the Internet, but existing solution did not work for me :(
Can anyone help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

I Faced same issue in Ubuntu 12.04 while installing iPlanet 7.0.15, and i solved it by installing ia32-libs looks like ia32-libs is missing in 12.04, please refer below URL which helped me to solve this issue.

https://forums.oracle.com/thread/2360480